# Как правильно согласовать времена в предложении?

Tags: времена

извините, я хотел узнать, в чем заключается согласование времен в русском языке? В сложных предложениях, например, основная и придаточная части обязательно должны быть в одном времени или только однородные?

Можно ли сказать "Я слышал, как он подходит ближе и как кладет что-то на стол", "Я сидела и смотрела, как он рисует"?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке нет чётких правил видо-временной соотнесённости при построении сложных предложений, согласование времён семантическое, лишь бы не было явных логических ошибок: *Я сижу и смотрю, как он рисовал*. Момент времени всё же один, и **время сказуемого должно быть одно**. А вот в этом случае разность времён обусловлена точкой отсчёта времени: *Вчера я сидел и смотрел, как он рисует* (рассказчик вчера наблюдал, как в это же время кто-то рисует - соблюдение времени наблюдения и рисования по факту, но всё это было вчера, поэтому сказуемое главного предложения в прош.вр).

**Выбор глагольных форм, указывающих на временной сдвиг, определяется, как правило, соотнесённостью действия, выраженного сказуемым придаточного предложения, с определённым моментом времени в настоящем, прошедшем или будущем.** Так, если действие придаточного предложения предшествует действию главного, то есть относится к более раннему моменту времени в прошлом, грамматически это выражается на уровне вида в русском языке: Я знал, что натворил мой друг. Главный глагол  имеет несовершенный вид, тогда как глагол сказуемое придаточного, выражающий предшествование, употребляется, как правило, в прошедшем времени и имеет совершенный вид.

В именных придаточных, выступающих в роли членов предложения, связанных со значением предметности, мы наблюдаем как семантический, так и синтаксический типы временной зависимости, что объясняется тесной смысловой и структурной взаимосвязью между частями данной группы сложноподчинённых предложений.

В обстоятельственных придаточных, которые, как правило, употребляются в качестве различных обстоятельств внешних отношений, случаи синтаксического согласования практически отсутствуют, так как в силу функциональных особенностей типы придаточных, относящиеся к данной группе, характеризуются относительной самостоятельностью по отношению к главным предложениям.

Помимо структурного и функционального критериев большое значение при согласовании имеет также и стилистический фактор. Если говорить о стилистической обусловленности проявления семантического и синтаксического согласования в различных типах придаточных предложений, то следует сказать, что в художественном стиле с его эталонностью преобладает синтаксическое согласование в сложноподчинённых предложениях с придаточными именными, определительными и в косвенной речи.

Газетно-публицистические тексты отличаются логически последовательным изложением, цитированием и введением различных типов чужой речи. Информационная функция газеты предполагает документально-фактологическую точность, официальность, некую обобщённость и абстрагированность в подаче материала. Эти особенности газетно-публицистического стиля обуславливают преобладание семантического согласования в газетных и журнальных текстах.

Научная речь характеризуется усложненным синтаксисом. Сложноподчиненный тип предложений преобладает среди других типов, при этом первое место по употребительности занимают предложения с придаточными определительными, причины и условия. Глагольные формы как в настоящем, так и в прошедшем времени приобретают **вневременное** значение, что приводит к преобладанию семантического согласования в научных текстах.

Так что Ваши примеры вполне корректны, там нет логической ошибки, просто временной сдвиг в изложении фактов. Однако в первом предложении всё равно не хватает какого-то указания на момент отсчёта времени. Можно сказать так: *В тот момент я слышал, как он подходит ближе и как кладет что-то на стол"*

Answer (score 1):

> в чем заключается согласование времен в русском языке?

Для практических нужд изучающих русский язык, не претендуя на исчерпывающую полноту,  проблему можно изложить довольно коротко:  ***в русском языке нет грамматически предопределенных правил согласования видо-временных форм, возможны любые сочетания.***

При этом, однако, смысл высказывания, сочетающего разные временные формы, может определяться контекстом или просто домысливаться, особенно в разговорной речи. И лишь в отдельных случаях, преимущественно при употреблении глаголов совершенного вида возникают логические противоречия, препятствующие употреблению.
При этом надо иметь в виду, что в придаточном предложении семантика времени может определяться как абсолютным отношением (прошлое, настоящее и будущее по отношению к моменту высказывания), так и относительным (до, во время или после действия главного предложения). По крайней мере в одном случае, если оба сказуемых выражены глаголами несовершенного вида в прошедшем времени, определить, какой подход использован, невозможно.

Вот для вашей фразы все сочетания при несовершенном виде глаголов.

Семантика фраз в этом списке - одна из возможных, дается как пример.

***Я сижу и смотрю, как он рисует.*** - он рисует сейчас, когда я на него смотрю.
***Я сижу и смотрю, как он рисовал.*** - он рисовал раньше, я смотрю видео, которое   снято в момент рисования.
***Я сижу и смотрю, как он будет рисовать*** - это разговорная форма, имеется в виду, что наблюдатель смотрит на подготовку к рисованию или ожидает его начала.

***Я сидел и смотрел, как он рисует.*** - он рисовал в момент, когда я на него смотрел.
***Я сидел и смотрел, как он рисовал.*** - тут есть варианты. Рисовать он может или в момент, когда я на него смотрю - или еще раньше, как в варианте с видео.
***Я сидел и смотрел, как он будет рисовать*** - смотрел я раньше, а рисовал он позже момента, когда я смотрел, то есть речь опять-таки о подготовке к рисованию или ожидании.

***Я буду сидеть и смотреть, как он рисует.*** - он будет рисовать в момент, когда я на него буду смотреть.
***Я буду сидеть и смотреть, как он рисовал.*** - ну это опять-таки про видео, которое я буду смотреть в будущем.
***Я буду сидеть и смотреть, как он будет рисовать*** - это случай, когда оба действия - в будущем, причем скорее всего происходят одномоментно.

Обобщение на глаголы совершенного вида может нарушить эту стройную картину. Например
***Я сидел и смотрел, как он нарисует*** может иметь семантику не относительного будущего, а продолженного перфекта (он только начал рисовать, а я жду окончания работы), но это никак не следует из грамматики и определяется только контекстом.
По счастью, такие страшноватые конструкции почти не используются в живом языке, так что в большинстве случаев грамматическое время придататочного просто соотносится с реальным относительным или абсолютным временем высказывания.
Остальное уже выходит за рамки грамматики.